# Getting a single result using findstr

Tags: findstr

I'm new to using CMD for things like this, so please forgive me. Just trying to use a simple command from CMD to search for a string in multiple files in multiple directories. What I have is:

```
findstr /s /l /c splay *.* > result.txt
```

However, this also pulls results like display instead of splay, I just want results for splay but I'm having problem finding a way to isolate this. I've searched online and here, maybe I'm just missing the obvious. Thanks in advance.